# Task Parallel.ForEach that report in the middle of work

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application that play files, every file has its own running time, i just add my files into my `Listview` and click on play button.

this is my function that received List as input, this list include all my files and because i want the option to running more than 1 file simultaneously i can control the number of parallel files:

```
public void doWork(IEnumerable<string> source, int parallelThreads )
{
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(source,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
}
```

when file finish running another file start to play (in case i choose to play several file simultaneously) and in the case i want to update my UI that specific file finished, how can i know in real time from the Task that specific file finish and another file start ?

Comment: How about creating an event that the UI can subscribe to? Simply trigger the event every time a task completes. Just make sure to `Invoke` into the UI thread before updating the UI.

Comment: Can i have an example ? (i am a new developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not in a position to test this with a compiler and I haven't done WinForms in a while, so there may be some minor syntax errors here, but this ought to get you going in the right direction:

```
... In your form code ...

ClassNameHere myOb = new ClassNameHere();
myOb.FileComplete += new FileCompleteHandler(FileDone);

...

public void FileDone(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new FileCompleteHandler(FileDone), new object[] { sender, e });
        return;
    }

    ... update UI here ...
}
```

Then, in your class that performs the actual work (you can, of course, call the class whatever you want).

```
public delegate void FileCompleteHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
public class ClassNameHere
{

    protected virtual void OnFileComplete()
    {
        FileCompleteHandler handler = FileComplete;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void doWork(IEnumerable<string> source, int parallelThreads )
    {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(source,
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = parallelThreads //limit number of parallel threads 
                    },
                    file =>
                    {
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;
                        //do work...

                        // This is where we tell the UI to update itself.
                        OnFileComplete();
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

        }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
                t =>
                {
                    //finish...
                }
            , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
            );
    } 

    public event FileCompleteHandler FileComplete;
}
```